# What are the improvements included on the Raspberry Pi Model A+

Tags: pi-models

I have just read that there is a new model Raspberry Pi coming called the A+. What are the improvements added to this board and how does it compare with the recently released Model B+?

Are there any software restrictions that apply to the A+ that do not apply to the B+ (or even the B)?

Comment: See here: https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/model-a-plus/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are several improvements most of which mirror those introduced with the model B+:

- A smaller form factor compared to the other models (including the A),
- Improved layout (compared to the model A),
- Combined 4-pole jack for connecting your stereo audio out and composite video out (like the model B),
- Better audio. The audio circuit incorporates a dedicated low-noise power supply (compared to the Model A and B).
- Expanded GPIO, now comes with 40 GPIO pins like the B+ (the A and B models only had 26) and is compatible with the HAT standard for add-on boards. **See Joan's comment below regarding the usable number of GPIO pins**.
- Better power management (compared to the A + B models).
- Now uses a micro SD card (compared to the model A).
- It is also cheaper $20.

As for software you may need to be running a newer version of the Kernel and Firmware, like with the B+.

Additional info can be found on the [element 14 website](http://www.element14.com/community/docs/DOC-70725?ICID=RPi-APlus-topbanner#overview), and from the [raspberrypi.org site](http://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/#raspberry-pi-model-a-plus-on-sale)

Comment: There are 40 pins on the expansion header.  There are only 26 usable gpios connected to those pins, the rest are ground rail, 3V3 rail, 5V rail, and (2) reserved gpios.

Comment: Agreed @joan, but the wording is from the horses mouth so to speak (the raspberrypi.org site see link above) More GPIO. The GPIO header has grown to 40 pins. The Model A+ is compatible with the HAT standard for add-on boards.

Comment: @joan What is the point of the extra pins for ground rail?  Is it just so that it can accept HAT compliant add-ons?

Comment: @maple_shaft I'm not a hardware type. Convenience, I think.  Almost every device you connect to the Pi will need a ground connection. The same can't be said for power (most devices will need power but they may need 3V3, 5V, or another lower of higher value).

Comment: @joan But there is already a ground pin on the 26 pin model.  Any type of pin connection needs a ground pin.

Comment: Having ground pins close to the signal connections improves signal integrity and reduces EMC issues for high speed signals.